# How to specify constraints in statsmodels OLS?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am using statsmodels OLS to run some linear regression on my data. My problem is that I would like the coefficients to add up to 1 (I plan to not use constant parameter).

Is it possible to specify at least 1 constraint on coefficients in statsmodels OLS? I see no option to do so.

Comment: [The unaccepted answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261018/how-to-add-sum-to-zero-constraint-to-glm-in-python) might help.

Answer (score 4):

[Thanks to @josef for pointing out the problem with my initial answer, which I am now re-writing]:

This can't be done in `statsmodels` OLS.

However, it can still be done with `statsmodels` but using the GLM function instead. A Generalized Linear Model with Gaussian family distribution for the response and identity link function is equivalent to the OLS model.

Here, we simulate some data and show that the two approaches give the same results:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

np.random.seed(15)

N = 1000
x1 = np.random.normal(10, 2, N)
x2 = np.random.normal(20, 4, N)
y = 50 + x1 + 2*x2 + np.random.normal(0, 5, N)

df = pd.DataFrame({'y': y, 'x1': x1, 'x2': x2})

# Fit the linear regression model (OLS)
m0 = smf.ols('y ~ x1 + x2', data=df).fit()
print(m0.summary())

# Fit the GLM model with Gaussian family and identity link
m1 = smf.glm('y ~ x1 + x2', data=df, family=sm.families.Gaussian(sm.families.links.identity())).fit()
print(m1.summary())
```

which results in:

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     50.5703      1.148     44.039      0.000      48.317      52.824
x1             0.9408      0.080     11.699      0.000       0.783       1.099
x2             2.0084      0.040     50.404      0.000       1.930       2.087
==============================================================================

                 Generalized Linear Model Regression Results                                               
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     50.5703      1.148     44.039      0.000      48.320      52.821
x1             0.9408      0.080     11.699      0.000       0.783       1.098
x2             2.0084      0.040     50.404      0.000       1.930       2.087


==============================================================================
```

which verifies that these are the same. Then we can proceed to specify the constraints. Here we will impose the constraint that `x1 + x2 = 2`:

```
# Define the constraint (e.g., coefficients of x1 and x2 summing to 1)
constraints = 'x1 + x2 = 2'

# Fit the GLM model with constraints
m_constrained = smf.glm('y ~ x1 + x2', data=df, family=sm.families.Gaussian(sm.families.links.identity())).fit_constrained(constraints)
print(m_constrained.summary())
```

which produces:

```
                 Generalized Linear Model Regression Results                  
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     61.9126      0.408    151.790      0.000      61.113      62.712
x1             0.1832      0.037      4.913      0.000       0.110       0.256
x2             1.8168      0.037     48.711      0.000       1.744       1.890
==============================================================================

Model has been estimated subject to linear equality constraints.
```

...and we obtain estimates of 0.1832 and 0.1832 which sum to exactly 2:

```
print(m_constrained.params['x1'] + m_constrained.params['x2'])
2.0
```

Comment: Answer looks good, except that OLS does not have `fit_constrained`. GLM has `fit_constrained` and estimates the same model as OLS with default family and link (gaussian family and identity link)

Comment: @Josef Doh !!!! Thanks for catching that. Answer re-written.