# Constrained regression in Python

Tags: python, regression

I have this simple regression model:

```
 y = a + b * x + c * z + error
```

with a constraint on parameters:

```
c = b - 1
```

There are similar questions posted on SO (like [Constrained Linear Regression in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Constrained%20regression%20python/)). However, the constraints' type is `lb <= parameter =< ub`.

What are the available options to handle this specific constrained linear regression problem?

Comment: algebraically eliminate b or c, do the regression and calc c or b   could even do the algebra in sympy if it were complicated enough to justify

Comment: @f5r5e5d algebraically eliminating b or c will lead to another constrained model. To be more specific, one can rewrite the original regression equation as  `y = a + b * (x + z) - z + error`  which is equivalent to `y = a + b * w - d * z + error, s.t. d = 1` (where `w`, the new regressor, is `x + z`). Moreover, this reformulation of the original problem suffers from collinearity.

Comment: Just an idea: Have a look at the [cvxopt](http://cvxopt.org/) module.

Comment: @Javad You can move the z to the left hand side, y - z ~ a + b (x + z) + error. statsmodels has `fit_constrained` for some models, but maybe not OLS.

Comment: @user333700 this is a neat idea indeed! It transforms the original constrained model to an (unconstrained) OLS and parameter b (and consequently c) can be perfectly identified. However, this sort of reformulation probably won't work for more complicated types of constrained linear models.

Comment: @Javad This reparameterization works in general for linear and affine constraints, it just requires some linear algebra.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261018/how-to-add-sum-to-zero-constraint-to-glm-in-python  for GLM including gaussian but not available yet for OLS

Comment: @user333700 isn't OLS a special case of GLM? Do you think one can use GLM with a linear link function and Gaussian family for errors, and then apply the `fit_constrained` method? I'm new to GLM and still trying to read through different sources. Also, the fact that apparently Generalized Linear Model is distinct from General Linear Model but both are known as GLM doesn't help.

Comment: @Javad Yes, using GLM with gaussian link should be the same as the reparameterized OLS. It should be easy to check this in your case with a relatively simple constraint by comparing the results. The availability of some of the extra features differ between GLM and the equivalent special case models. GLM has a bit more overhead in the computation than OLS, because it uses the generic GLM framework for estimation.

Comment: There's this package `clogistic` that has very similar API to scikit-learn. It provides constrained logistic regression: https://github.com/guillermo-navas-palencia/clogistic

Answer (score 8):

This is how it can be done using GLM:

```
import statsmodels
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

# Set the link function to identity
statsmodels.genmod.families.links.identity()

OLS_from_GLM = sm.GLM(y, sm.add_constant(np.column_stack(x, z)))

 '''Setting the restrictions on parameters in the form of (R, q), where R 
 and q are constraints' matrix and constraints' values, respectively. As
 for the restriction in the aforementioned regression model, i.e., 
 c = b - 1 or b - c = 1, R = [0, 1, -1] and q = 1.'''

res_OLS_from_GLM = OLS_from_GLM.fit_constrained(([0, 1.0, -1.0], 1))

print(res_OLS_from_GLM.summary())
```

Comment: The call to the `links.identity()` doesn't do anything. Choosing a link would have to be through an argument in `GLM`. However, identity is the default link for Gaussian and doesn't need to be specified.

Comment: @user333700 From the `statsmodels.genmod.families.links` docstring: _Defines the link functions to be used with GLM and GEE families_. So, it seems that the link function can be set through this statement. Setting it through an argument in GLM call might be a possibility but I couldn't find anything about it. Also, as you mentioned identity is the default of the link function.

Comment: Yes, that creates a link instance, but to be used in the model it has to be provided to the model as argument. A single statement like this could only have an effect if it would change some global variables. However, statsmodels does not use global variables because it would be very easy to get unexpected results if somewhere something changes those globals.

Comment: @user333700 thanks for clearing that up. So, to wrap up, using GLM in its default form (Gaussian errors and identity link function) suffices as an alternative to OLS, with the added possibility of defining linear constraints on the parameters. However, if one wants to use other families (like Gamma) and link functions (like inverse_power), something like this can be done: `link_func = statsmodels.genmod.families.links.inverse_power` and then `OLS_from_GLM = sm.GLM(y, X, family = sm.families.Gamma(link=link_func))`

Answer (score 3):

There are a few constrained optimization packages in Python such as CVX, CASADI, GEKKO, Pyomo, and others that can solve the problem. I develop [Gekko](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for linear, nonlinear, and mixed integer optimization problems with differential or algebraic constraints.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

# Data
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)
z = np.random.rand(10)

# Gekko for constrained regression
m = GEKKO(remote=False); m.options.IMODE=2
a,b,c  = m.Array(m.FV,3)
a.STATUS=1; b.STATUS=1; c.STATUS=1
x=m.Param(x); z=m.Param(z)
y = m.Var();  ym=m.Param(y)
m.Equation(y==a+b*x+c*z)
m.Equation(c==b-1)
m.Minimize((ym-y)**2)
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve(disp=True)
print(a.value[0],b.value[0],c.value[0])
```

This gives the solution that may be different when you run it because it uses random values for the data.

```
-0.021514129645 0.45830726553 -0.54169273447
```

The constraint `c = b - 1` is satisfied with `-0.54169273447 = 0.45830726553 - 1`. Here is a comparison to other [linear regression packages in Python](https://apmonitor.com/pds/index.php/Main/LinearRegression) with an without constraints:

[image: Constrained Linear Regression]

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

# Data
x = np.array([4,5,2,3,-1,1,6,7])
y = np.array([0.3,0.8,-0.05,0.1,-0.8,-0.5,0.5,0.65])

# calculate R^2
def rsq(y1,y2):
    yresid= y1 - y2
    SSresid = np.sum(yresid**2)
    SStotal = len(y1) * np.var(y1)
    r2 = 1 - SSresid/SStotal
    return r2

# Method 1: scipy linregress
slope,intercept,r,p_value,std_err = linregress(x,y)
a = [slope,intercept]
print('R^2 linregress = '+str(r**2))

# Method 2: numpy polyfit (1=linear)
a = np.polyfit(x,y,1); print(a)
yfit = np.polyval(a,x)
print('R^2 polyfit    = '+str(rsq(y,yfit)))

# Method 3: numpy linalg solution
#       y =     X a
#   X^T y = X^T X a
X = np.vstack((x,np.ones(len(x)))).T
# matrix operations
XX = np.dot(X.T,X)
XTy = np.dot(X.T,y)
a = np.linalg.solve(XX,XTy)
# same solution with lstsq
a = np.linalg.lstsq(X,y,rcond=None)[0]
yfit = a[0]*x+a[1]; print(a)
print('R^2 matrix     = '+str(rsq(y,yfit)))

# Method 4: statsmodels ordinary least squares
X = sm.add_constant(x,prepend=False)
model = sm.OLS(y,X).fit()
yfit = model.predict(X)
a = model.params
print(model.summary())

# Method 5: Gekko for constrained regression
m = GEKKO(remote=False); m.options.IMODE=2
c  = m.Array(m.FV,2); c[0].STATUS=1; c[1].STATUS=1
c[1].lower=-0.5
xd = m.Param(x); yd = m.Param(y); yp = m.Var()
m.Equation(yp==c[0]*xd+c[1])
m.Minimize((yd-yp)**2)
m.solve(disp=False)
c = [c[0].value[0],c[1].value[1]]
print(c)

# plot data and regressed line
plt.plot(x,y,'ko',label='data')
xp = np.linspace(-2,8,100)
slope     = str(np.round(a[0],2))
intercept = str(np.round(a[1],2))
eqn = 'LstSQ: y='+slope+'x'+intercept
plt.plot(xp,a[0]*xp+a[1],'r-',label=eqn)
slope     = str(np.round(c[0],2))
intercept = str(np.round(c[1],2))
eqn = 'Constraint: y='+slope+'x'+intercept
plt.plot(xp,c[0]*xp+c[1],'b--',label=eqn)
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```