# How to make statsmodels GLM.fit_constrained result picklable/store-and-reloadable

Tags: python, pickle, reload, statsmodels, glm

A GLS (or thus also OLS) regression with constraints on parameters can readily be run using [statsmodels GLM.fit_constrained()](https://docs.w3cub.com/statsmodels/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.glm.fit_constrained/) method, as with the code below (or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41928276)).

**How can I make the GLMresults object resulting from such a statsmodels GLM.fit_constrained() regression picklable**, so that the estimation result can be stored for re-use for prediction in a new session anytime later?

The GLMresults object obtained from fit_constrained() and containing the relevant estimation result has its [.save()](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults.save.html#statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults.save) method that would normally readily pickle the object into a file.

This .save() works for the result from a standard (unconstrained) GLM regression, sm.glm.fit(). However, it doesn't work with the result for sm.glm.fit_unconstrained(). Instead, it throws a pickling error, seemingly because patsy DesignMatrixBuilder is not Picklable, so it links to the never resolved [issue here](https://github.com/pydata/patsy/issues/26). This at least for my Python 3.6.3 (running on Windows).

An example:

```
import statsmodels
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd

# Define exapmle data & Constraints:
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDF'))
y = df['A']
X = df[['B','C','D','F']]
constraints = ['B + C + D', 'C - F'] # Add two linear constraints on parameters: B+C+D = 0 & C-F = 0
statsmodels.genmod.families.links.identity()
OLS_from_GLM = sm.GLM(y, X)

# Unconstrained regression:
result_u = OLS_from_GLM.fit()
result_u.save('myfile_u.pickle') # This works

# Constrained regression - save() fails
result_c = OLS_from_GLM.fit_constrained(constraints)
result_c.save('myfile_c.pickle') # This fails with pickling error (tested in Python 3.6.3 on Windows): "NotImplementedError: Sorry, pickling not yet supported. See https://github.com/pydata/patsy/issues/26 if you want to help."
```

Is there a way to readily make the result from fit_unconstrained() picklable i.e./or storable?

**I below suggest a first workaround answer; it is trivial and works well for me so far. I do not know, however, whether it is truly advisable or whether its risks are large and/or any preferable alternative solution exists.**

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, I didn't know patsy's constraints cannot be pickled. I opened https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/6427

Comment: @Josef: Great, and I like your suggestion there to change fit_constrained to store the more raw constraint instead of the problematic MatrixDesignBuilder element!

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by simply removing (commenting out) the line
`res._results.constraints = lc`
in the function definition of `fit_constrained()` within statsmodels' active `generalized_linear_model.py` script (in my case in the virtualenv folder *\env\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\generalized_linear_model.py*).

Idling this line seems to have created no problem for my work; I can now readily save and reload the pickled file and use it to make correct predictions based on the stored estimation; the imposed parameter constraints remain respected and predictions made using .predict() remain unchanged after reloading.

I wonder though whether there is any major risk attached to this procedure. I am not familiar with the inner workings of the statsmodels library, or with its glm.fit_constrained() method in particular. i reckon it's unadvisable to change anything in a pre-existing module one does not understand. However, it is the only way I am conveniently able to impose various constraints to my GLM parameters and to be able to save the regression results to readily re-use it for prediction in a later session.

Comment: simpler workaround might be to set the `constraints` attribute to None before pickling, something like `result_c._results.constraints = None`

Comment: @Josef: Maybe! But is this really simpler? It could be more confusing: if later I'd have to understand from the stored object whether any constraints had been used and I find the explicit 'None' I'd think there were _no_ constraints; if the variable doesn't exist at all, I'd rightly know to not know. Or maybe I'm wrong because the .constraints member is anyways part of the object and explicitly setting to None avoids a possibly bad value.. [in which case it could be considered whether the class/object should be redefined in first place to not contain the .constriants member at all]

Comment: It's much simpler in the sense that you don't have to edit the statsmodels source on your computer. If you want to remove the attribute, then you could `del` it in the results instance before pickling. You have still other attributes specific to `fit_constrained` like `results.k_constr`.

Comment: `fit_constrained` returns a regular results instance. When it returns a constrained Results instance, then the constraint information can be added to summary. But that's not the case yet.

Comment: You're of course right with "... = None" (I mixed sth up before); much better than to change the sm source code. If you post that as an official answer I guess it deserves to be the accepted one. Also the 'del' you propose seems promising, I didn't know that feature, thanks.