# Python - Setting constraints on coefficients of dummy variables regression

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Is there a way in python where I can add a constrain to my OLS with dummy regression variables? I had a look at [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105424/how-can-i-constrain-the-coefficients-from-linear-regression-to-sum-to-a-given-va?newreg=a29566b60b5b4867abc79908674fedea) with a possible solution in R.

I am using pandas `get_dummies()` on my dataframe , without setting the `drop_first` to TRUE.

Ideally I would like to then use either `statsmodel` or `scipy` to run a regression with the constraint which says the sum of weighted coefficients of each of my set of categorical variable = 0

======== Below is the model and the constraint I am trying to implement ======

`y_{i}(t) = \alpha(t)+\sum_{r=1}^{14}\beta_{r}(t)*Rating^{r}_{i}(t)+\sum_{s=1}^{20}\gamma_{s}(t)*Sector^{s}_{i}(t)+\sum_{c=1}^{5}\sigma_{c}(t)*Country^{c}_{i}(t) ............ (1)`
where

`\sum_{r=1}^{14}\beta_{r}(t)*weight(t) + \sum_{s=1}^{20}\gamma_{s}(t)*weight(t)+ \sum_{c=1}^{5}\sigma_{c}(t)*weight(t) = 0 ........... (2)`

The above is the constraint I want to force on my model in equation (1)

Apologies, but I am not sure how to put latex equations here..

Comment: What are the weight functions?

Comment: It's not available for statsmodels OLS but it is for GLM which defaults to Gaussian. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261018/how-to-add-sum-to-zero-constraint-to-glm-in-python and the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261018/how-to-add-sum-to-zero-constraint-to-glm-in-python