# Constrained GLM in statsmodels

Tags: r, python-3.x, numpy, statsmodels

I'm trying to do a constrained optimization in statsmodels.

[How to add sum to zero constraint to GLM in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261018/how-to-add-sum-to-zero-constraint-to-glm-in-python)

The solution shown above works for me, but as I have almost 100 variables it's cumbersome to write out the whole constraint out as,  var[1]  + var[2]...+ var[100]=0 as shown in the solution.

If there a shortcut to set all the coefficients for one variable to zero, similar to the R Style constraints shown in the question of the same link?

Thanks

Baz

Comment: You can create the restriction matrix directly, but you need to know the position of the parameters that are included in the sum to zero constraint.

Comment: Are the positions the same as that shown in the glm.summary()? Do you have to include the intercept when you are looking at the positions?