# How to constrain coefficients of coupled univariate linear regressions?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have a simple system of linear equations:

```
m_i * x + c_i = y_i
```

subject to the constraint that the set of slope coefficients, `m_i`, sum to 0.

I'm looking for a Python solution to fit this equation to some observational time series, ideally using scipy or statsmodels, as that will make it easier to quantify sampling variability and confidence intervals.

I've messed around with statsmodels general linearised model class, but haven't managed to wrangle my problem into the right shape.

Comment: Take a look at lmfit, specifically how the `Parameter`s can have an algebraic constraint based on other parameters (optional parameter `expr`), which seems to be what you want. https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/parameters.html#lmfit.parameter.Parameter

Comment: Post data and the code you've attempted so far

Comment: `GLM.fit_constrained` allows for linear and affine constraints, example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261018/how-to-add-sum-to-zero-constraint-to-glm-in-python/29266239#29266239 Constraints would have to be defined in terms of the `m_i` parameter names.